# Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring data elasticsearch in my spring boot app. I set 400 threads in tomcat settings. We deployed it on aws ECS and we are using 8 contaners.
My rest high client config is

```
@Value("${elasticSearchUrl}")
private String elasticSearchUrl;

@Override
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(elasticSearchUrl)));
    return restHighLevelClient;
}
```

I am using es repository to save:

```
public interface ExceptionRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Exception, String> {}

e.g
exceptionRepository.saveAll(updatedExceptions);
```

I get this error:Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED in Spring.
I saw a few similiar questions but every was related to async usage of es. AFAIK in my case I am using it in sync way. Please tell me what I can do.

Comment: Is your application built as a reactive app? Not the Spring Data Elasticsearch part, but the main application?

Comment: No, it's not. It's simple sync spring rest controller.